Is it possible to save parts of a code in a variable?
Here is one part of my script:
if (PNG == 1) {
    set terminal png size 1024,768 font "Arial,11"
    SAVE_AS = FILENAME.'.png'
    print "    - Create file: ".SAVE_AS
    set output SAVE_AS
    plot DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb "red" axis x1y1,\
         DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb "blue" axis x1y2
}

if (SVG == 1) {
     set term svg size 600,400 dynamic font 'Arial,11'
     SAVE_AS = FILENAME.'.svg'
     print "    - Create file: ".SAVE_AS
     set output SAVE_AS
    plot DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb "red" axis x1y1,\
         DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb "blue" axis x1y2
}

As you can see the plot DATA_FILE ... occurs twice in my code, once in the PNG-part and once in the SVG-part. Is it possible to put the code in some kind of a variable and then refers to this variable.
Here is some pseudo code:
a = DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb "red" axis x1y1,\
    DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb "blue" axis x1y2

if (PNG == 1) {
    ...
    plot a
}

if (SVG == 1) {
     ...
    plot a
}

Edit:
Here the entire script:
# Run as follows:
#    
#  gnuplot.exe -e "DATA_FILE='<path/to/root/>/input/PEDS_1.csv'; PIC_FOLDER='<path/to/root/>/output';
#                  SEQ='PEDS_1'; X_MAX=50; PNG=1; SVG=1" <filename>.gplt
#
# The variables are as follows:
#  DATA_FILE : The output CSV file
#  PIC_FOLDER: The full path of the folder, where the created graphs should be saved
#  SEQ       : The name of the Sequence
#  X_MAX     : The maximum simulation time (in hours) to be displayed. Default value is 50:
#  PNG       : Set 1 if a PNG graph should be created. Default value is 0.
#  SVG       : Set 1 if a SVG graph should be created. Default value is 0.

# Set default values
if(!exists('X_MAX')){
     X_MAX = 50
}

if(!exists('PNG')){
     PNG = 0
}

if(!exists('SVG')){
     SVG = 0
}

# Get the filename of this gnuplot script
SCRIPT_FILENAME = ARG0[strlen(ARG0)-8:strlen(ARG0)-5]

# Set the filename (without extension)
FILENAME = PIC_FOLDER.'/'.SEQ.'___'.SCRIPT_FILENAME

set encoding utf8
set datafile separator ','
set key autotitle columnhead
set title "KPDS «".SEQ."»" noenhanced

# x-Axis
set xlabel 'Time (h)' offset -2,0,0
set xrange [0:X_MAX]
set mxtics 10

# y-Axis
set ylabel 'Power (MW)' textcolor "red" offset 2,0,0
set yrange [0:100]
set ytics textcolor "red"
set mytics 10

# y2-Axis
set y2label 'Pressure (bara)' textcolor rgb "blue" offset -2,0,0
set y2range [0:100]
set y2tics textcolor rgb "blue"
set my2tics 10

# Grid
set grid linetype 2 linewidth 0.2 linecolor rgb '#DCDCDC'
set grid mxtics
set grid mytics

# Legend
set key off title

if (PNG == 1) {
    set terminal png size 1024,768 font "Arial,11"
    SAVE_AS = FILENAME.'.png'
    set output SAVE_AS
    plot DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb 'red' axis x1y1,\
         fname using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb 'blue' axis x1y2
}

if (SVG == 1) {
    set term svg size 600,400 dynamic font 'Arial,11'
    SAVE_AS = FILENAME.'.svg'
    set output SAVE_AS
    plot DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb 'red' axis x1y1,\
         fname using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb 'blue' axis x1y2
}

Sorry for the first posting, where I miss to provide it.

I think what you are after is a macro. Gnuplot supports expanding string variables in commands. Eg var="using 1:3"; plot 'data.txt' @var . However, var has to be a constant string!

Gnuplot version 6 answer (not applicable to earlier versions)
function $myplot(filename) <<EOF
    plot filename using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb "red" axis x1y1,\
         filename using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb "blue" axis x1y2
EOF

if (PNG == 1) {
    ...
    evaluate $myplot(DATAFILE)
} else if (SVG == 1) {
     ...
    evaluate $myplot(DATAFILE)
}

Gnuplot version 5 answer
Earlier versions of gnuplot did not support function blocks but did  allow use of the evaluate command to execute a string variable or string-valued function. The string is limited to a single line of text.
a = "plot DATAFILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb 'red' axis x1y1, DATAFILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb 'blue' axis x"

if (PNG == 1) {
    ...
    evaluate a
} else if (SVG == 1) {
     ...
    evaluate a
}


The second solution (Gnuplot version 5 answer) works. But I don't like the restriction 'The string is limited to a single line of text' because the code is more difficult to maintain.

I am using gnuplot 6. Unfortunately, I got at evaluate $myplot(DATA_FILE) the error undefined value. I am aware that you named the variable DATAFILE, but in my code its DATA_FILE.

Please show the exact commands you used.   I was assuming something like DATA_FILE = "somedir/somename.dat";    evaluate $myplot(DATA_FILE).  The function is expecting a string; it doesn't matter at all what the name of that string is.

I did some more debugging outputs. The code enters the function and the variable filename has the same value as DATA_FILE, which is a valid path. Here the output: Inside $myplot: c:\Users\...\01_Parameters/AELS_1.csv (I have only shorten the filepath with ...). For now I will stick with your other approach, but its interesting to underdand why its not working.

If you want to write your plotting command only once, but get it as one or several different output formats, you can use the command replot (check help replot). However, this works only if you don't have a multiplot graph (check help multiplot). For multiplots you need to do it differently.
My default terminal is wxt.
So, it will plot the graph first in wxt terminal, and if PNG==1 also into a PNG file and if SVG==1 also into a SVG file.
Edit:
If you don't want a graph in your default terminal, you can set the terminal to unknown. This will plot nothing but will give a warning in gnuplot console which, however, you can ignore.
Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.

Script: (I prefer complete and fully working copy&paste scripts)
### create several output files with identical plot command
reset session

BASENAME = "SO78571143"
PNG      = 1
SVG      = 1

set term unknown
plot sin(x), cos(x)    # your actual plot command

if (PNG == 1) {
    set term pngcairo size 640,348 font "Arial,11"
    OUTPUT = BASENAME.'.png'
    print "    - Create file: ".OUTPUT
    set output OUTPUT
    replot
}

if (SVG == 1) {
    set term svg size 600,400 dynamic font 'Arial,11'
    OUTPUT = BASENAME.'.svg'
    print "    - Create file: ".OUTPUT
    set output OUTPUT
    replot
}
set output  # close output file
### end of script

Result: PNG output and a similar SVG output


Your solution works fine. Do you know how to suppress the opening of the window showing the graph, which occurs after plot DATA_FILE ...?

@ped see modified answer.

Thanks. You are absolutely right: I could and should have created a minimal example. Please excuse me.

@ped don't worry. Sometimes it's essential to have the script and the data to reproduce an error or a certain behaviour. Maybe not in your case here, but it doesn't hurt to get some result without having to create some meaningful data first and to complete a snippet of a script. I want to make sure that all the script I'm posting here are working and are tested. So, problem solved, question answered? If yes, then please accept one of the answers which solved your problem.

I'm not familiar with Gnuplot but couldn't you move the common code to after the if statements to reduce duplication?
if (PNG == 1) {
    set terminal png size 1024,768 font "Arial,11"
    SAVE_AS = FILENAME.'.png'
    print "    - Create file: ".SAVE_AS
    set output SAVE_AS
}

if (SVG == 1) {
     set term svg size 600,400 dynamic font 'Arial,11'
     SAVE_AS = FILENAME.'.svg'
     print "    - Create file: ".SAVE_AS
     set output SAVE_AS
}

plot DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('POW-FP+D')) with lines title 'POW-FP+D' linecolor rgb "red" axis x1y1,\
     DATA_FILE using ($1/3600.0):(column('PR-Core')) with lines title 'PR-Core' linecolor rgb "blue" axis x1y2

